# NetBeans 8 "Certified Plugins" update url deleted by mistake

Tags: android, url, netbeans, plugins

I was trying to add the Android plugin to Netbeans *8.0.2* and while attempting to update the URL, I accidentally deleted the "Certified Plugins" URL under the "Settings" tab. Can anyone copy and paste the URL so I can restore the lost plugin, please? ( I'm sorry but I cannot post images yet, not enough reputation. From NetBeans just go to Tools->Plugins->Settings , click on the "Certified Plugins" config from the left panel, edit and then just copy the url. )  I'm just trying to avoid reinstalling NetBeans. :-)  Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the link:

```
http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.0.2/uc/final/certified/catalog.xml.gz
```

Btw, you can browse through any offical repository in your broswer, just open one of the default links and delete the `catalog.xml.gz`

---

For the sake of completeness:

**Certified Plugins**

```
http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.0.2/uc/final/certified/catalog.xml.gz
```

**NetBeans Distribution**

```
http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.0.2/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz
```

**Plugin Portal**

```
http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/updates/8.0/catalog.xml.gz
```

Urls as in NB 8.0.2; the version can be changed to whatever is needed.

Comment: You need to have https instead of http.